# Reading dbf files

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

I need to read and write dbf files. Microsoft dropped support for this in Office 2013.

I am trying to use OLEDB. The problem I am having at this point (have not gone into the writing) is that when I read the header info I am having it returned sorted alphabetically while the rows are not sorted like that. I need to have them saved in the same order so that I can go back and create a dbf files (after some data processing) to pass back to my legacy applications which require DB.

This is for internal distribution so I can take care of having the correct .NET library if necessary. I can't find any reference that solves this problem and I rather use a .NET technology than writing dbf from scratch...

I apologize if this ha been answered before is this is the case I'd appreciate being pointed to the correct way of accomplishing this task.

## Code to follow

```
if (intype == 6)  //dbase
{
    int rowCount = 0;
    int colCount = 0;
    string npath = filein;
    i = npath.LastIndexOf("\\");
    aux2 = MySubStr(npath, i + 1, 1);  // directory  --- internal library
    auxstr = MySubStr(npath, i + 1, 2);
    i = auxstr.IndexOf(".");
    if (i > -1)
        auxstr = MySubStr(auxstr, i, 1);                         
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection connection;
    string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = '"; // I can change this to proper library
    connstr = string.Concat(connstr, aux2);
    connstr = string.Concat(connstr, "';");
    connstr = string.Concat(connstr, "Extended Properties='dBASE 5.0';");  // again not worried about DBASE 3 or 4
    connection = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();                            
        DataTable dbSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, auxstr, null });
        i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow rownm in dbSchema.Rows)
        {
            header[i] = rownm["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
            myDT[i++] = rownm["DATA_TYPE"].ToString();  // not using at this point... will be used when writing dbfs
        }
        colCount = i;

        aux2 = "Select * from ";
        aux2 = string.Concat(aux2, auxstr); 
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(aux2, connection);
        da.Fill(ds,"ZDATA");
        count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        auxstr = e.ToString();
        messages[cntmsgs++] = auxstr;
        zcode = 99;
        logerror(messages, cntmsgs, zcode);
        return 99;
    }
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(aux2, connection);
    OleDbDataReader reader;
    reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    StreamWriter ftmp = new StreamWriter(fileout[0], false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (rowCount == 0)
        {
            auxstr ="";
            for (i = 0; i < colCount -1; i++)
            {
                auxstr += "\"" + header[i] + "\",";
            }
            auxstr += "\"" + header[colCount - 1] + "\"";
            ftmp.WriteLine(auxstr);
            rowCount++;
        }
        aux2 = "";
        for (i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
                auxstr = "";
            else
                auxstr = reader.GetString(i);
            auxstr = "\"" + auxstr + "\"";
            if (i < reader.FieldCount - 1)
            {
                auxstr = string.Concat(auxstr, ",");
                aux2 = string.Concat(aux2, auxstr);
            }
            else
            {
                aux2 = string.Concat(aux2, auxstr);
            }
        }
        ftmp.WriteLine(aux2);
    }
    ftmp.Close();
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
    filein = fileout[0];
    intype = 2;  // right now forcing additional processing in another block...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of noise that I think is hiding the true problem.  Can you simplify the code (string concatenation, path generation, file reading, refactor into methods) so the true problem will be easier to find?

Comment: Are you sure you want to write it from scratch? There are a lot of DBF editors, free or commercial...

Answer (score 0):

You mention .dbf files, but are they really dBASE 5 or was that just a connection you were able to get.  I personally have utilized Microsoft's [Visual Foxpro OleDb provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).  You can make a connection, query the tables, build parameterized select, insert, update, delete and don't need to really know about header and such.

There are many questions about connections to dbf tables and such, but I normally use an OleDbDataAdapter, put my command to execute in that and pull the data via .Fill() into a DataTable object.

Then I can do things like

```
foreach( DataColumn dc in MyTable.Columns )
   [write whatever output of things like dc.ColumnName, dc.Type, etc]

foreach( DataRow dr in MyTable.Rows )
{
   write out...  dr["WhateverColumn"]
}
```

No, not exact code, but simple to work with.  Building commands to push data back is easy  too.  But if your big deal is writing the content out...  Are you really trying to rewrite the table and reconverting everything to strings?

The other comment about too much noise is accurate... In summary, yes, Microsoft dropped support for whatever, but what do you WANT to do.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on the visual foxpro driver. I had placed this project in the back burner and now I have some free time to pursue this project. I do need to work on the file in order to prepare it for some legacy software. Sorry for the delay on the response.